# Blackberry: (Java) Post/Get data

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm writing a little application for my BlackBerry and I need to send some data to a webpage (Via GET or POST)

Can anyone advise on the way to do this with the BlackBerry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) for this. The linked javadoc contains basic code examples for both GET and POST. Here's an extract of the GET example:

```
 void getViaStreamConnection(String url) throws IOException {
     StreamConnection c = null;
     InputStream s = null;
     try {
         c = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);
         s = c.openInputStream();
         int ch;
         while ((ch = s.read()) != -1) {
             ...
         }
     } finally {
         if (s != null)
             s.close();
         if (c != null)
             c.close();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Does this allow me to send data via Get/Set ?

Comment: My bad, didnt see the link. - Thanks